# 'poetry install' command fails; *.whl files are not found

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am managing dependencies in my Python project via Poetry.

Now I want to run this project in a machine which is different from my dev machine. To install dependecies, I simply run this command from the root directory:

```
$ poetry install
```

but then it raises the following errors:

```
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

Writing lock file

Package operations: 70 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing colorama (0.4.4)
  • Installing tzdata (2021.1)

  ValueError

  File \C:\Users\tteguayco\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\9e\b3\11\7d87ac44fdb2d557301f1f4086a37c080d1482a98751abe7cdbabbad26\colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl does not exist

  at ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\poetry\core\packages\file_dependency.py:40 in __init__
       36│             except FileNotFoundError:
       37│                 raise ValueError("Directory {} does not exist".format(self._path))
       38│
       39│         if not self._full_path.exists():
    →  40│             raise ValueError("File {} does not exist".format(self._path))
       41│
       42│         if self._full_path.is_dir():
       43│             raise ValueError("{} is a directory, expected a file".format(self._path))
       44│


  ValueError

  File \C:\Users\tteguayco\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts\45\2d\cb\6443e36999e7ab3926d5385dfac9ee9ea2a62f8111ff71abb6aff70674\tzdata-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl does not exist

  at ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\poetry\core\packages\file_dependency.py:40 in __init__
       36│             except FileNotFoundError:
       37│                 raise ValueError("Directory {} does not exist".format(self._path))
       38│
       39│         if not self._full_path.exists():
    →  40│             raise ValueError("File {} does not exist".format(self._path))
       41│
       42│         if self._full_path.is_dir():
       43│             raise ValueError("{} is a directory, expected a file".format(self._path))
       44│
```

It would be good to know what these *.whl are and how they are used by Poetry.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Specifically I found that deleting the `AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\artifacts` folder (I'm on Windows 10) worked for me. virtualenvs for other projects may be in `AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs` so you might not want to delete the root cache folder at `AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache` in its entirety.

Comment: This worked for me after getting the OP's error following a change of location of my poetry project.

Comment: Same here - many thanks @Dris101.

Comment: The answer is right, but the problem recurs all the time and it is impossible to clear the cache every time. I solved with poetry self update, versione 1.1.12 seems not to have the error

Answer (score 4):

According to https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4163, it seems to be an issue still pending to be resolved.

As a workaround, dumping dependencies to a `requirements.txt` file via `poetry`:

```
$ poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt --without-hashes
```

and then installing them via `pip`, worked for me:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be related to poetry cache. For me, it works as intended if i go to `User\user\AppData\Local\pypoetry` and I delete the cache folder.

Comment: There is ...AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache and ...AppData\Local\Cache\cache. This answer seems a little confusing regarding the two.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was missing visualstudio build tools as this question states.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/136595/error-microsoft-visual-c-140-or-greater-is-require.html

I downloaded and installed it and everything works fine now.

Answer (score -1):

For me the bug is gone with the latest poetry release `>=1.1.12`

So running `poetry self update` should fix it.

Fixed issue: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/4549

1.1.12 poetry release: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/releases/tag/1.1.12